# Divs are Overlapping in CSS

Tags: html, css

I know this question is answered but I can't figure out why my divs are overlapping. Earlier today the header was overlapping the navbar and now the container is overlapping the header and the navber.

This is what it looks like -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EnCP.jpg

CSS and HTML

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'HaloOutline';
  src: url('/core/HaloOutline.ttf') format('truetype');
}

sup {
 font-size:14px; font-family:HaloOutline!important;
}

/* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
    cursor: pointer;
}
#showUser {
 display:none; position:relative; z-index:100; background:#1b272c; opacity: 0.5;
}

body
{  
 min-height:100%;
    background-color: #131416 ;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
 background-size: cover;

}

.dialog { display:none; }

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#container {
  width: 80%;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0px auto;
  background: #1c1e21;
  opacity: 0.9;
}
/* NAVIGATION section ====================== */

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#1c1e21+0,2f3237+50,26282c+51,383c42+100 */
  background: #1c1e21;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #1c1e21 0%, #2f3237 50%, #26282c 51%, #383c42 100%);
  /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #1c1e21 0%, #2f3237 50%, #26282c 51%, #383c42 100%);
  /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #1c1e21 0%, #2f3237 50%, #26282c 51%, #383c42 100%);
  /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#1c1e21', endColorstr='#383c42', GradientType=0);
  /* IE6-9 */
  height: 15px;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 80%;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  margin: auto;
}
.navbar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 6px;
  min-width: 100%;
}
.navbar > ul > li {
  min-width: 25%;
  text-align: center;
}
.navbar > ul > li > ul {
  display: none;
}
.navbar > ul > li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
.navbar ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Arial;
  padding: .2em 1em;
  color: #bcc1c7;
}
.navbar ul li a:hover {
  border: solid 1px #5d646f;
  color: #858c99;
  background-color: #2e3238;
  border-top-right-radius: .2em;
  border-bottom-left-radius: .2em;
}
/* HEADER section ========================== */

header {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  background-image: url("http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/halo/images/c/c1/Forge_world.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/2000?cb=20100723045607");
  background-position: center center;
  position: relative;
  transition: background-image 1s ease-in-out;
}
header {
  height: 200px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top:2.5%;
  color: white;
  background-image: url("http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/halo/images/c/c1/Forge_world.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/2000?cb=20100723045607");
  background-position: center center;
  position: relative;
  transition: background-image 1s ease-in-out;
}
header img {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
header:hover {
  background-image: url("http://images.gamersyde.com/image_halo_reach-13325-1852_0004.jpg");
}
header img.top:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}
aside {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: flex;
  width: 20%;
  line-height: 100%;
  background: #2e3338!important;
}
aside hr {
  width: 90%;
}
aside img {
  width: 90%;
}
aside ul {
  width: 90%;
  text-align: justify;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  margin-left: -10%;
  margin-right: auto;
  opacity: 1.0;
  padding: 10px;
  list-style-type: none;
}
aside ul li {
  min-width: 100%;
  margin-left: 25%;
  margin-right: 25%;
}
aside ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #bcc1c7;
}
aside ul li a:hover {
  color: #25282c;
  padding: 4px;
  background-color: #c7cbd1;
}
aside h3 {
  background: #202020;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}


/* MAIN ========================================= */

main
{
    float: left;
 display:block;
    width: 77%;
 color: white;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 16px;
 padding:10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:1em;

}

main a {
  text-decoration: none;
 color:grey;
}

main a:hover {
 text-decoration:none;
 color: #60808F;
}

hr {
 border-color: #25282c;
 width: 760px;
}

p {
 margin: 20px;
 color: #bcc1c7;
}

j {
 margin: 1px;
 color: #bcc1c7;
}

article {
 background: url("img/Panellong.png");
 background-size: contain;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center;
 padding: 20px;
}

h2 {
 text-align: center;
 color: #bcc1c7;
 letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}

h1 {
 text-align: center;
 color: #bcc1c7;
 letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}

img {
 max-width: 100%;
 max-height: 100%;
 display: block;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}

/* FOOTER ========================================= */

#footer {
 clear:both;
 color: #bcc1c7;
 text-align: center;
 border-top:1px dashed grey !important;
 margin-top: 40px;
 border-bottom-left-radius:1em;
 border-bottom-right-radius:1em;
 padding: 15px;
 font-size: 90%;
 font-family: Arial;
 background-color: #2e3338;
 max-width: 100%;
 position:relative;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}

#footer a {
  text-decoration: none;
 color:grey;
}

#footer a:hover {
 text-decoration:none;
 color: #60808F;
}

fieldset {
 padding: 20px;
 margin: 20px 0;
 border: 1px solid #5d646f;
}

legend {
 padding: 10px;
 font-size: 18px;
 letter-spacing: 0.1em;
 color: #bcc1c7;
}

input[type="password"],
input[type="username"],
input[type="name"],
input[type="email"],
input[type="age"],
input[type="text"]{
 display: block;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 padding: 10px 10px 10px 25px;
 border: 0;
 border-radius: 3px;
 background-color: #25282c;
 color: #fff;
 width: 300px
}

textarea {
 display: block;
 padding: 10px 10px 10px 25px;
 border: 0;
 border-radius: 3px;
 background-color: #25282c;
 color: #fff;
 width: 70%;
 height:200px;
}

label {
 padding: 5px;
 font-size: 14px;
 letter-spacing: 0.1em;
 color: #bcc1c7;
}

input[type="submit"],
input[type="button"],
button {
 border: solid 1px #5d646f;
 background: #25282c;
 width:150px;
 height: 30px;
 border-top-right-radius: 1em;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 1em;
 letter-spacing: 0.1em;
 color: #bcc1c7;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Halo Editing Community</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/core/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//halovau.lt/js/vader-jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="//halovau.lt/js/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  <script src="//halovau.lt/js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//halovau.lt/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/fingerprintjs2/1.4.1/fingerprint2.min.js"></script>
<script>
<!--
    function toggle_visibility(id) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
       else
          e.style.display = 'block';
    }
//-->

 </script>
 

</head>

<body>




<div class='dialog' id='dialog0' title='Allied Websites'>
 <center><a href='//halovau.lt'><b>HaloVault</b></b><img src='https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/227232976763748355/237104871386513409/halovauliconSAFE3.png' width='50%' alt='HALO VAULT' title='HaloVault' /></a>
 <a href="http://www.xboxchaos.com"><b>Xbox Chaos</b><img alt="" border="0" src="http://i.imgur.com/gelB8qc.png" />  </a>
 <br />
 <a href="http://www.macgamingmods.com"><b>Mac Gaming Mods</b><img alt="" border="0" src="http://i.imgur.com/CzwS1LZ.png" />  </a>
 <br />
  <a href="http://www.halo3archives.com"><b>Halo 3 Archives</b><img alt="" border="0" src="https://halo3archives.com/images/banner.jpg" />
   <br /></center>
</div>    
<?php if (!isset($_USER['id'])) {$staff = "<li><a href=\"/application.php\">Recruitment</a></li>";}
 elseif (isset($_USER['id']) OR isset($_SESSION['uname'])) {
 $panel=''; if ($_USER['group'] > 1){ $panel = "<a href='/leg3ndary'>♛ Staff Panel</a><br />"; }
 $staff = "<li><a href='javascript:void();' class='uClick' onclick=\"toggle_visibility('showUser')\" class='dropbtn'>".$_USER['name']." ▼</a>\n"
 ."<div id='showUser''><center><img title='Click to view your profile.' style='cursor:pointer;' onclick=\"location.href='/members.php?id=".$_USER['id']."';\" width='110' src=\"".$_USER['img']."\" /><br />\n
 <a href='/articles.php?new=link'>☲ Submit Download</a><br />\n
 <a href='/articles.php?new=tutorial'>☲ Submit Tutorial</a><br />\n
 ".$panel."\n
 <a href='/logout.php'>&#128274; Logout</a></center></li></div>";
} ?>
 <div class="wrapper">

  <div class="navbar">

    <ul class="navbar">
      <li><a href="/index.php">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="/members.php">Members</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="/archive.php">Archive ▼</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Community Portal</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Blog Posts</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Mod/Map Downloads</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <?=$staff;?>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <header>
    <img class="bottom" src='/core/img/logolight.png' />
    <img class="top" src='/core/img/logo.png' />
  </header>



  <div id="container">

    <aside>
      <ul>
        <br />
        <?php if(!isset($_USER[ 'id'])) { ?>
        <li><a href="login.php">Login Page</a>
        </li>
        <?php } ?>
        <br />
        <li><a class='dialog_link' data-dialog='dialog0' href="javascript:void();">Allied Websites</a>
        </li>
        <br />
        <li><a href="changelog.php">Change Log</a>
        </li>
        <br />
        <li><a href="/articles.php?cat=tutorials">Getting Started</a>
        </li>
        <br />
      </ul>
      <br />

    </aside>

  </div>
```

```html
<?php require_once "core/structure.php"; include_once "core/top.php"; ?>


              <main>
              <article>
              <h2>Halo Editing Community<sup>alpha</sup></h2>
              </article>
      <br /><br /><p>Welcome to the Halo Editing Community, a place where we preserve and archive the beauty of Halo as it lasted under it's original founders Bungie. Here you can find all sorts of Halo mods, tips and tutorials. </p>
      <br />
       <br />
      <hr />
      <img src="https://s16.postimg.org/ywmshllmd/framed.png">
      <h2>
       Holiday Cards
      </h2>
      <p>
       "Wake up! The enemy!" - To other Grunts.
      </p>
              </main>

<?php include_once "core/bottom.php"; ?>
```

Comment: Use flex layout instead of floats

Comment: it is the way you style...make wrapper the parent element to display:flex and remove floats on the child elements and adjust it accordingly

Comment: Ok thank you very much!

Comment: The header is still overlapping the navbar. I made wrapper parent to the navbar div, got rid of the floats and made it display:flex.

Comment: Not Sure if this is what you want...http://codepen.io/sahithiK/pen/JbydWG?editors=1100

Comment: Please confirm or just give an overview of how exactly you need it

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me. That is better. But I would ideally have the navbar resting exactly ontop of the header. And if you can see, one of the drop downs is still being overlapped by the header.

Comment: Thats because of the margin-top on header element,it ideally has to be the height of the nav bar ...

Comment: modified the code and updated in the answer check it

Comment: Heres the link to the website so you can see it. Ill update the code so you can see all of it. http://hec.halovau.lt

Comment: You won't be able to view the contents within main because they are located in a separate file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use display:flex for the layout instead of floats for layouts.
check this snippet

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'HaloOutline';
  src: url('/core/HaloOutline.ttf') format('truetype');
}
sup {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: HaloOutline!important;
}
/* Dropdown Button */

.dropbtn {
  cursor: pointer;
}
#showUser {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
  background: #1b272c;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: #131416;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
.dialog {
  display: none;
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#container {
  width: 80%;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0px auto;
  background: #1c1e21;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.navbar-container {
  position:relative;
  /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#1c1e21+0,2f3237+50,26282c+51,383c42+100 */
  background: #1c1e21;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #1c1e21 0%, #2f3237 50%, #26282c 51%, #383c42 100%);
  /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #1c1e21 0%, #2f3237 50%, #26282c 51%, #383c42 100%);
  /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #1c1e21 0%, #2f3237 50%, #26282c 51%, #383c42 100%);
  /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#1c1e21', endColorstr='#383c42', GradientType=0);
  /* IE6-9 */
  height: 25px;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 80%;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  margin: auto;
  padding:5px;
}
ul.navbar  {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;

  min-width: 100%;
}
ul li{
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-decoration:none;
}

ul.navbar  > li {
  min-width: 25%;
  text-align: center;
}
ul.navbar  > li > ul {
  list-style-type:none;
  display: none;
  position:absolute;
  right:10;
  z-index:1;
}
ul.navbar > li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
  padding:10px;
}
.navbar  li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Arial;
  padding: .2em 1em;
  color: #bcc1c7;
}
.navbar ul li a:hover {
  border: solid 1px #5d646f;
  color: #858c99;
  background-color: #2e3238;
  border-top-right-radius: .2em;
  border-bottom-left-radius: .2em;
}
/* HEADER section ========================== */

header {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  background-image: url("http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/halo/images/c/c1/Forge_world.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/2000?cb=20100723045607");
  background-position: center center;
  position: relative;
  transition: background-image 1s ease-in-out;
}
header {
  height: 200px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: white;
  background-image: url("http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/halo/images/c/c1/Forge_world.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/2000?cb=20100723045607");
  background-position: center center;
  position: relative;
  transition: background-image 1s ease-in-out;
}
header img {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
header:hover {
  background-image: url("http://images.gamersyde.com/image_halo_reach-13325-1852_0004.jpg");
}
header img.top:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}
aside {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: flex;
  width: 20%;
  line-height: 100%;
  background: #2e3338!important;
}
aside hr {
  width: 90%;
}
aside img {
  width: 90%;
}
aside ul {
  width: 90%;
  text-align: justify;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  margin-left: -10%;
  margin-right: auto;
  opacity: 1.0;
  padding: 10px;
  list-style-type: none;
}
aside ul li {
  min-width: 100%;
  margin-left: 25%;
  margin-right: 25%;
}
aside ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #bcc1c7;
}
aside ul li a:hover {
  color: #25282c;
  padding: 4px;
  background-color: #c7cbd1;
}
aside h3 {
  background: #202020;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
/* MAIN ========================================= */

main {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  width: 77%;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 1em;
}
main a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: grey;
}
main a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #60808F;
}
hr {
  border-color: #25282c;
  width: 760px;
}
p {
  margin: 20px;
  color: #bcc1c7;
}
j {
  margin: 1px;
  color: #bcc1c7;
}
article {
  background: url("img/Panellong.png");
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  padding: 20px;
}
h2 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #bcc1c7;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #bcc1c7;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
/* FOOTER ========================================= */

#footer {
  clear: both;
  color: #bcc1c7;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 1px dashed grey !important;
  margin-top: 40px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 1em;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 1em;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 90%;
  font-family: Arial;
  background-color: #2e3338;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
#footer a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: grey;
}
#footer a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #60808F;
}
fieldset {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px 0;
  border: 1px solid #5d646f;
}
legend {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  color: #bcc1c7;
}
input[type="password"],
input[type="username"],
input[type="name"],
input[type="email"],
input[type="age"],
input[type="text"] {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 25px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #25282c;
  color: #fff;
  width: 300px
}
textarea {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 25px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #25282c;
  color: #fff;
  width: 70%;
  height: 200px;
}
label {
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  color: #bcc1c7;
}
input[type="submit"],
input[type="button"],
button {
  border: solid 1px #5d646f;
  background: #25282c;
  width: 150px;
  height: 30px;
  border-top-right-radius: 1em;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 1em;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  color: #bcc1c7;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  
    <div class="navbar-container">
      
        <ul class="navbar">
   <li><a href="/index.php">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="/members.php">Members</a></li>
   <li><a href="/archive.php">Archive ▼</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Community Portal</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Blog Posts</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Mod/Map Downloads</a></li>
    </ul> 
   </li>
   <?=$staff;?>
  </ul>
   </div>
  <header>
      <img class="bottom" src='/core/img/logolight.png' />
      <img class="top" src='/core/img/logo.png' />
    </header> 

  
       
<div id="container">

   <aside>
    <ul>
     <br />
     <?php if(!isset($_USER['id'])) { ?><li><a href="login.php">Login Page</a></li> <?php } ?>
     <br />
     <li><a class='dialog_link' data-dialog='dialog0' href="javascript:void();">Allied Websites</a></li>
     <br />
     <li><a href="changelog.php">Change Log</a></li>
     <br />
     <li><a href="/articles.php?cat=tutorials">Getting Started</a></li>
     <br />
    </ul>
   <br />

   </aside>
  
</div>

  
  
</div>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you. That stopped the overlapping for the header. But all of the contents within the container which I didn't include in the code is pushed out of the container now. And the dropdown is still behind the header.

Comment: Ill put it up on the original question.

Comment: And when the both are combined. It looks like this http://hec.halovau.lt

Comment: your markup you added it on the snippet ,why is it splitted

Comment: Modified the code snippet,the navbar section both div and nav has the same class , i have modified a bit so that archive's list comes over when clicked on it...I hope it helps